# What is the name for Flutter's sliver-like behaviors?

Tags: gui-design, terminology, component

I'm looking for a component name that behaves like flutter's sliver:

[Here](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/material/app_bar_pinned_floating_snap.mp4) is an example of sliver.

What i'm looking for exactly is a list that collapses or expands based on how much you dragged, pretty much like the behavior Android launchers have when you drag the app list, if it's >50% then it expands, else it collapses back to its minimised state.

What is the name of this kind of component/behavior?

Comment: Is it not “sliver”? :)

Comment: @Lynn Sadly no, that's a specific named implementation for flutter.

Comment: Auto shrink header on scroll or shrink header

Answer (score 1):

The [ScrollPhysics](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html) provides [Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/index.html)'s [FlexibleSpaceBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html) class its **stretch behavior**.

A related concept (component) is [overscroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior) as implemented by [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), where you have a dialog box with scrolling content on top of a page of scrolling content. See also: "[CSSWG - CSS Overscroll Behavior](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overscroll/)".

Once the dialog box's scroll boundary is reached, the underlying page will then start to scroll — this is called [scroll chaining](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/overscroll-behavior#scrollchaining).

To customize the physics:

- AndySham - [scroll-custom](https://github.com/AndySham/scroll-custom) - Overwrites native DOM scrolling with a customisable physics-based animation.
- JulianShapiro - [velocityJS](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity) - Accelerated JavaScript animation.

Rather than replace one large library with another to implement the physics it makes sense to use a simple [parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax) effect:

- electerious - [basicScroll](https://github.com/electerious/basicScroll) - Standalone parallax scrolling for mobile and desktop with CSS variables.

With that code a smaller movement can be translated to a larger move that fully pulls down the [AppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html).